# How to use Widget on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Now I'm developing a new WebSite using WordPress.
I don't know how to use widgets.
I tried to search on google so I found some answer.
Here is my code.

```
class WP_Widget_Home extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Sets up the widgets name etc
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('id_widget_home',
      __('(TrueLove) [PAGE] Home', 'TrueLove'),
      array('description' => __('Intro page.', 'TrueLove')));
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the content of the widget
     *
     * @param array $args
     * @param array $instance
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // outputs the content of the widget
        echo "<h1>I like U!</h1>";
        the_content();
    }
...
function registerHomeWidgetFunc()
{
  return register_widget("WP_Widget_Home");
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'registerHomeWidgetFunc');
```

I can insert (TrueLove) [Page] Home widget on WidgetPage('wp-admin/widgets.php').
That's all.
How can I use this?

Comment: This code goes to active theme `functions.php` then appearance => widgets and drag widget to right widget. I assume you page template has widget area defined ;)

Comment: Yeah, but how can i get widgets in sidebar?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Wpuyb9B.png

Comment: Thank you @Beneris. Your comment helped me so mush to solve this problem.